# SQL developer insert data error

Tags: sql, oracle

I have no idea why I am getting this error. Does anybody have any ideas?

```
Error starting at line : 19 in command -

    INSERT INTO Employee 
    (Eno, Ename, Zip, Hdate, Creation_Date,Created_by, Last_Update_Date, Last_Update_By )
    VALUES 
    (111111, "Man", '01234', 'Jan-10-1999','Jan-10-1999', "Hank", 'Jan-10-1999', "Hank")
```

> Error at Command Line : 22 Column : 80 Error report - SQL Error:
>   ORA-00984: column not allowed here
>   00984. 00000 -  "column not allowed here"

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements003.htm#SQLRF00218

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quote strings with `'`:

```
INSERT INTO Employee 
(Eno, Ename, Zip, Hdate, Creation_Date,Created_by, Last_Update_Date, Last_Update_By )
VALUES 
(111111, 'Man', '01234', 'Jan-10-1999','Jan-10-1999', 'Hank', 'Jan-10-1999', 'Hank');
```

`"name"` is treated as identifier.

Answer (score 0):

`"Man"`, `"Hank"`, and `"Hank"` should be in single quotes, like this: `'Man'`, `'Hank'`, and `'Hank'`. Character strings inside double-quotes are taken to be quoted column names. That's why the error is `column not allowed here`.

And while we're on it, if `HDate`, `Creation_Date`, and `Last_Update_Date` are of datatype DATE you're flirting with disaster here by counting on the database interpreting a string as a date in a particular way. Best to use the `TO_DATE` function to convert the string into a real DATE:

```
INSERT INTO Employee 
(Eno, Ename, Zip, Hdate,
 Creation_Date,Created_by, Last_Update_Date,
 Last_Update_By )
VALUES 
(111111, 'Man', '01234', TO_DATE('Jan-10-1999' 'MON-DD-YYYY'),
 TO_DATE('Jan-10-1999', 'MON-DD-YYYY'), 'Hank', TO_DATE('Jan-10-1999', 'MON-DD-YYYY'),
 'Hank')
```

Best of luck.